# Is it possible to avoid sync in Ethereumj, but still register a listener?

Tags: synchronization, ethereumj

I'm attempting to create an contract analysis application using Ethereumj. I don't need to participate as an Ethereum node on the network and thus I'm trying to avoid having to sync the entire blockchain history. I'm curious if it is possible to register a listener in a purely passive mode.

I tried the following with no success:

```
SystemProperties.getDefault().setSyncEnabled(false);

val ethereum = EthereumFactory.createEthereum();
ethereum.addListener(new EthereumListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onTransactionExecuted(TransactionExecutionSummary summary) {
        log.info("Summary: {}", summary);
        super.onTransactionExecuted(summary);
    }
});
```

However, no callback is triggered.